# Magento layout and blockcode as plain text in template?

Tags: layout, template, apache2

I have setting up a linux machine based on ubuntu server and deployed an existing magento shop for locale testing purposes. Now I cleared cache /var/cache, change DB and url path settings and when I try to open the main shop site, I see several PHP or Layout instructions as plain text in frontend theme:

For Example (shown as text in quellcode viewed in frontend):

```
<!--?
$this--->removeLinkBlock('top-link-cart');
?&gt;
```

or

```
<!--? if($_product--->hasSpecialPrice()):
                    $_price = $_product-&gt;getPrice();
                    $_specialPrice = $_product-&gt;getSpecialPrice();
                    $_priceDiff = round((100 - ($_specialPrice * 100 /         $_price)) * 1);
                    $_priceDiff = round($_price - $_specialPrice);
                endif; ?&gt;
```

phtml files are rendered correctly by php engine and I also checked CHMOD permissions. Anybody have an idea where can I solve this issue?

Comment: check .htacess file,  i think something wrong with it

Comment: Checked - I also tried to replace with original magento 1.9 htaccess - no change :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution - I must enable:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

On apache php.ini. I thought it was enabled by default.